# writerow method in python - Additonal commas in the output

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

Additional commas in the output

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4GZn.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

bf = pd.read_csv('blackfriday.csv')
bf_null_columns=bf.columns[bf.isnull().any()]
bf_null_columns_list = bf_null_columns.to_list()

with open("output.csv", "a", newline='') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter='')
    writer.writerow(str(len(bf_null_columns_list)))
    writer.writerows(bf_null_columns_list)
```

Comment: Why i'm getting additonal commas in the output

Comment: It looks like `bf_null_columns_list` is a **`string`** not a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using writer.writerows which expects a two-level iterables (rows, columns).

You are providing one-level list of strings (columns) as a consequence each string is used a iterables of letters and writerows writes them comma-separated.

If you want to write one column per line you should add one level to your iterable.

Maybe you could switch to writerow which expects a one-level iterable:

```
for column in bf_null_columns_list:  # column is a string
    writer.writerow(list(column))
```

Comment: I used write method. That was working fine. Thank you, MrMey